# Improper use of slices causes unintended side effects

Tags: go, append, slice

I have the following function that generateс all subsets of a given array.

The idea is simple - I start with a results array that contains an empty set (slice) and for each element in the input array `nums` go over all previously generated sets, add the current element of `nums` to them and add the resulting new sets back to the results array. Nothing particularly interesting.

```
func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
  result := [][]int{{}}
  for _, n := range nums {
    newSets := [][]int{}
    for _, set := range result {
      newSets = append(newSets, append(set, n))
    }
    result = append(result, newSets...)
  }
  return result
}
```

The problem is that using `append(newSets, append(set, n))` corrupts the `result` slice, of which `set` is a member. I modified the function a bit with some debug code (see below) and also found a workaround (the commented code) which doesn't cause the same behavior.

I very much suspect that this is caused by something that's passed by reference instead of being copied (I am appending the elements of `newSets` to `result`). The problem is that I can't find it. :( I never change the result within a loop that iterates over it. I also work with new instances of `newSets` for each loop. So I'm not sure what's causing it. Please advise. :)

```
func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {

  result := [][]int{{}}
  for _, n := range nums {

    newSets := [][]int{}
    var before, after []int
    for _, set := range result {

      lastResultIdx := len(result)-1
      if lastResultIdx > 0 {
        before = make([]int, len(result[lastResultIdx]))
        copy(before, result[lastResultIdx])
      }

      //ns := []int{}
      //for _,v := range set {
      //  ns = append(ns, v)
      //}
      //ns = append(ns, n)
      //newSets = append(newSets, ns)

      newSets = append(newSets, append(set, n))

      if lastResultIdx > 0 {
        after = result[lastResultIdx]
        if before[len(before)-1]!=after[len(after)-1] {
          fmt.Println(n, "before", before, "after", after)
        }
      }
    }

    result = append(result, newSets...)
  }
  return result
}

func main() {
  subsets([]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
append(newSets, append(set, n))
```

The problem is not that it is a nested append. The problem is that you're assuming `append(set,n)` will return a new slice. That is not always the case. A slice is a view on an array, and when you add new elements to the slice, if the addition did not result in reallocation of the array, the returned slice is the same slice you passed in, with `len` field incremented. So when you're going through your results array, you're modifying the elements that are already there, and at the same time, adding them again as if they are different results.

To solve, when you get an element of the `result`, create a new slice, copy elements of the `result` to it, append the new element and then add the new slice to `result`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple enough: `append` takes a slice argument—`[]T` for some type *T*—plus of course the element(s) to append, and returns a `[]T` result.  But `[]T`, if non-nil, consists of two parts: a *slice header* that points to some backing array and carries a current length and capacity, plus the *backing array*.  When `append` does its job, it has a choice:

- modify the backing array in place, and return a new slice header that re-uses the existing backing array, or
- create a new backing array, copy the original values to the new backing array, and return a new slice header that uses the new backing array.

Whenever `append` *copies* the backing array, your code works.  Whenever it *re-uses* the backing array, your code may or may not work, depending on whether some other slice header is using the same backing array.

Suppose your backing array has length 5 for instance, and one of the existing slice headers reads "length 1, capacity 5" with element 0 of the backing array holding zero.  That is, the existing slice header `h` contains `[0]`.  Now you call `append(h, 1)`.  The append operation re-uses the backing array and puts `1` in the second element and returns a new slice header `h1` that contains `[0, 1]`.  Now you take `h` *again*, append `2`, and make a two-element slice `h2` holding `[0, 2]`.  But **this re-uses the same backing array that `h1` re-used** so now `h1` also holds `[0, 2]`.

To solve the problem without modifying your algorithm much, you need either:

- a variant of `append` that always copies, or
- a variant of *append one int to a slice of ints* that always copies.

The latter is simpler:

```
func setPlusInt(set []int, n int) []int {
    return append(append([]int(nil), set...), n)
}
```

which lets you replace one line of your existing code.

(I made one other trivial change [here](https://play.golang.org/p/YXtm-pON874) and added enough to provide a working example in the Go Playground.)

(An alternate solution is to set up each of your own slice headers to offer no extra capacity, so that `append` must always copy.  I have not illustrated this method.)